# Changing scope in controller initialization not working for directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("myDirective", myDirective);

function myDirective() {
  return {
    template: '{{vm.numbers}}',
    scope: {
      numbers: '='
    },
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
  };
}

function MyController($timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.numbers.push(3);
  $timeout(function() {
     vm.numbers.push(4);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <my-directive numbers="[1,2]"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Why 3 is not being pushed to the array?

Comment: You've created a function called "myController", but you are not applying it as a controller to your module, nor applying it to anything in your view to instantiate it.

Comment: @DavidPisoni it's a directive controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are obvious syntax difference between `=` and `@`. And one of the features of two-way `=` binding is that you should proceed with care when attribute value is something other than scope property name, because it wasn't meant for that.

What happens in your example is that '[1,2]' string was parsed to an array and is available as `vm.number` scope property when controller function is running. The changes that were made with `vm.numbers.push(3)` were applied to a copy of an anonymous array and they weren't observed anywhere. After controller function was finished, the first digest cycle launches, and `vm.number` is overwritten with `[1, 2]` array, again. After that `$timeout` function kicks in and makes another change with `vm.numbers.push(4)`. The changes in `vm.number` are observed only since this moment.

That's what happens when anonymous array or object is being fed to bi-directional directive binding. You will also have problems with assigning `vm.number` to something else.

Since `@` binding is good only for text, it isn't an option also. You can do this instead

```
function myDirective() {
  return {
    template: '{{vm.numbers}}',
    scope: {},
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
  };
}

function MyController($timeout, $parse, $attrs) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.numbers = $parse($attrs.numbers)() || [];
  vm.numbers.push(3);
  $timeout(function() {
     vm.numbers.push(4);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the controller executes, `vm.numbers` is updated per your logic. Then the link phase kicks in and the scope vars are set from your markup and the nameds in scope but you lose your interim changes from controller.

I added some console logs that show this sequence:

```
in controller=> [1, 2, 3]
in link, scope=> [1, 2, 3] attrs=> [1,2]
in timeout method=> [1, 2]
```

One approach is as suggested by @estus, to wire the parameters yourself. Another approach might be to rewrite your logic so that you can rely on angular to manage the passed.